# How can I set a class based on something being true / false with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following:

```
<i class="fa fw"
   data-ng-class="{'fa-flag-o': q.qs.tag == false; 'fa-flag': q.qs.tag == true}"></i>
```

This does not seem to be working and setting the class to fa-flag-o when q.qs.tag is false.

Is there something wrong with the way that I have coded this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use comma to separate the properties:

```
<i class="fa fw"
   data-ng-class="{'fa-flag-o': q.qs.tag == false, 'fa-flag': q.qs.tag == true}">
</i>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/OyOsOkaZ/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Also, you can write like this:

```
<i class="fa fw"
   data-ng-class="{'fa-flag-o': !q.qs.tag, 'fa-flag': q.qs.tag}">
</i>
```

Answer (score -1):

Common practice is to use:

```
<element class="visible-{{property}}"></element>
```

So you can use this css:

```
<style> 
    .visible-true{
                  display:inline;
                 }
    .visible-false{
                  display:none;
                 }
</style>
```

For example